# Is there any Ubuntu translation indicator?

Tags: software-recommendation, applet, translation

For more precision:

- I'm runnning Ubuntu 12.04
- I'd like an indicator which shows up to the left of the date/volume/wifi icons
- If possible I'd like to be able to change the translation language
- The indicator could use internet based translators (google translate etc.) or have a complete library come with it so translations can be obtained offline.

Relating to usability: I'd like to have it work in a way where you click on the indicator icon and you can start typing either directly or once a window has opened and it instantly shows the translation you need (with your target languages pre-set or determined in options).

Comment: Interesting idea. If none exist, then I can probably make one for you. You're only interested in translating _to_, right? You select the language you want to translate to, then a dialog appears and you enter text which is then translated to the language you chose?

Comment: Yes if you could I'd be incredibly grateful, alternatively a lens would work nicely too (was planning on maybe trying that myself as making some doesn't seem too hard, although I'd be messing around in the dark to begin with), and I guess it sounds like laziness to not simply open up google translate or whatnot, but I find it clearer and more hassle-free to not open a browser. If you happen to need a hand I've dabbled a bit with programming so give me a heads up if you'd need a hand, but if you could make one I'd be very grateful and sure others would be too :)

Comment: Send me an email to joerlend.schinstad@ubuntu.com and let's discuss it. This is a little bit limited. :)

Comment: Added to favs to give kudos for Jo-Erlend when he finishes this ;-)

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad I sent you an email a while back, you're probably pretty busy but just wanted to make sure you'd gotten it, if not I can resend it :)

Comment: Please do. I haven't noticed it.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad forgot to ping you in the post before, did you happen to get my mail perchance? (I don't know why it isn't working...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have gnome-shell installed, you could use this extension

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/397/traductor-gnome-shell/

It doesn't work if you're using Unity

Comment: Pending a Unity indicator this has worked perfectly thanks a lot!